# Thymeleaf conditional with two variables

Tags: html, spring-boot, conditional-statements, thymeleaf

I am currently trying to hide specific elements, if the creditUser in my app has credit less than the costs of a specific dish. (It's kind of a dish ordering system, just for training purposes) And I cannot figure out how to set up the thymeleaf condition, to make it work...

I've tried all kinds of solutions, but all I can find on the internet is something like this: th:if="*{ score < 20 and score >= 0}"

my current version looks like this:

```py
<td ><a th:if="${creditUser.credit} &gt; ${dish.small}" class="btn btn-success" th:href="@{/order/orderDish/(creditUserId=${creditUser.id},dishId=${dish.dishId},delId=${dish.delId},dishName=${dish.name},price=${dish.small})}" th:text="${dish.small}">Bestellen</a></td>
```

Now I don't get any error messages, but the element is also not showing up. Any suggestions on how to compare a value in thymeleaf to another value? (The creditUser is passed it is just not shown in the code part and the solution works with fixed values like creditUser.credit > 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything should be inside the same braces:
`th:if="${creditUser.credit > dish.small}"`

Comment: I don't get it..I think I've tried that yesterday and it didn't work...today it looks like it does :s ..thank you very much for your help!